# New column based on a rule AND equalling an changing value (python pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, called target, that I would like to fill, based on some rules, from an old dataframe, called source.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

target_d = {'ColA': ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3', 'a3', 'a4'],
            'ColB': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X'],
            'ColC': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7']
    }
target = pd.DataFrame(data=target_d)

source_d = {'Col1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
            'Col2': ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4'],
            'Col3': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'],
            'Col4': ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4'],
    }
source = pd.DataFrame(data=source_d)
source = source.set_index('Col1')

target.loc[target['ColB'] == 'X', 'ColC'] = source.loc['a1', 'Col4']
```

The above starts with our two input dataframes:

```
  ColA ColB ColC
0   a1    X   c1
1   a1    Y   c2
2   a2    X   c3
3   a2    Y   c4
4   a3    X   c5
5   a3    Y   c6
6   a4    X   c7

     Col2 Col3 Col4
Col1
a1     e1   f1   g1
a2     e2   f2   g2
a3     e3   f3   g3
a4     e4   f4   g4
```

to then update target to provide:

```
  ColA ColB ColC
0   a1    X   g1
1   a1    Y   c2
2   a2    X   g1
3   a2    Y   c4
4   a3    X   g1
5   a3    Y   c6
6   a4    X   g1
```

however, what I would like is:

```
  ColA ColB ColC
0   a1    X   g1
1   a1    Y   c2
2   a2    X   g2
3   a2    Y   c4
4   a3    X   g3
5   a3    Y   c6
6   a4    X   g4
```

I want to condition on the ColB value being X and to then use the ColA value to find the Col4 value in the source, by using the index.

I somehow want the right hand side of the equality to read

```
source.loc[target.loc['ContractID'], 'Col4']
```

to use my indexing to find which value I want. I don't know if I'm completely barking up the wrong tree since the right hand side is normally a fixed value in everything that I've seen.

Any ideas of how I can produce the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create a `dictionary` with `keys` being the `index` of source and respective `values` being Col4 of source.

Then, `map` map with `loc` (to locate where ColB equals 'X') to update your target `DF`:

```
d = dict(zip(source.index,source.Col4))
target.loc[target['ColB'].eq('X'), 'ColC'] = target['ColA'].map(d)
```

Prints:

```
>>> target

  ColA ColB ColC
0   a1    X   g1
1   a1    Y   c2
2   a2    X   g2
3   a2    Y   c4
4   a3    X   g3
5   a3    Y   c6
6   a4    X   g4
```

---

Setup:

```
>>> target.to_dict()

{'ColA': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'a2', 4: 'a3', 5: 'a3', 6: 'a4'},
 'ColB': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'X', 3: 'Y', 4: 'X', 5: 'Y', 6: 'X'},
 'ColC': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c2', 2: 'c3', 3: 'c4', 4: 'c5', 5: 'c6', 6: 'c7'}}

>>> source.to_dict()

{'Col2': {'a1': 'e1', 'a2': 'e2', 'a3': 'e3', 'a4': 'e4'},
 'Col3': {'a1': 'f1', 'a2': 'f2', 'a3': 'f3', 'a4': 'f4'},
 'Col4': {'a1': 'g1', 'a2': 'g2', 'a3': 'g3', 'a4': 'g4'}}
```